# Can a view define a __bobo_traverse__ method?

Tags: plone

I am trying to make ARFilePreview work with newer versions of Plone. The product defines a view which has its own `__bobo_traverse__` method. Unfortunately ZPublisher does not invoke this method.

The `traverseName()` method in `BaseRequest.py` has:

```
     if IPublishTraverse.providedBy(ob):
        ob2 = ob.publishTraverse(self, name)
     else:
        adapter = queryMultiAdapter((ob, self), IPublishTraverse)
        if adapter is None:
            ## Zope2 doesn't set up its own adapters in a lot of cases
            ## so we will just use a default adapter.
            adapter = DefaultPublishTraverse(ob, self)
            ob2 = adapter.publishTraverse(self, name)
```

I would like it to take the else case but it results in a 404 because the if returns True.

Is there an easy fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a method called publishTraverse(same args as `__bobo_traverse__`) and invoke the existing `__bobo_traverse__` from it.

Comment: Not sure if totally related, but this article could help: http://bluedynamics.com/articles/jens/plone-traverse_subpath-for-browserviews-view-some-more-path